# set cookie with session value

Tags: php, session, cookies

I cannot find in all the Q and A what i am looking for ( or i simply do not understand it (lol) ) so im hoping somebody can help me with this.

I'm trying to make a "settings save" system based on cookies. 
The settings are currently in a $_session[] and i would like to store them in a multidimensional array that goes into the cookie. 
I figured that something like this would work but apparently i am missing something or i don't understand the way the cookie needs it arguments.

My script looks like this:

```
$class1BP   =   $_SESSION["class1BP"];
$class1BP1  =   $_SESSION["class1BP1"];
$class1BP2  =   $_SESSION["class1BP2"];
$class1BP3  =   $_SESSION["class1BP3"];
$gedaanx    =   $_SESSION["gedaanx"];

$array = array( $class1BP, $class1BP1, $class1BP2, $class1BP3, $gedaanx);
setcookie('deel[1]', serialize($array);
```

So am i right that my array is wrong? Cause i don't know howto set cookies and never used it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to set in a cookie? There's almost always a better solution.

Comment: I'm trying to set the cookie with some session value's, like;    classbp contains "900" clasbp1 contains "233,345" etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating cookie but not giving the time for residing in system.

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30)); // 86400 = 1
```

day

may this work for u

Comment: Woops i also saw i missed a ) at the end, gonna try this one now.

Comment: What if i want to put multiply value's in the same cookie ? 
like: setcookie('offerte', $class1BP, $class1BP1, time() + (86400 * 30 * 30));  Cause this doesnt work..

Comment: you can't store multiple values in cookies. rather than you concatenate into one and then use explode function to retrieve the values.

Comment: Thnx, got everything working like i wanted! can't vote up but you got some points now :)